# React Hooks change data inside div instantly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a function that displays data in a div when a menu item is clicked.

```
const [activeCollapseKey, setActiveCollapseKey] = React.useState(0);
const [ drawerContent, setDrawerContent ] = useState(<div></div>);

let info = [];

function handleClick(index) {
                const divTitle = "Residence info";
                let res = openData.info;
                const {data} = res;

                info = [];
                _.isArray(data) ? residencesInfo = data : residencesInfo.push(data);

                let collapse = <Collapse accordion activeKey={[activeCollapseKey]} onChange={(key) => {
                                // @ts-ignore
                                setActiveCollapseKey(key);
                            }}>
                        {info.map((data, idx) => {
                            return <Panel header='test' key={idx + 1}>
                                testInfo
                            </Panel>

                        })}
                </Collapse>;

                setDrawerContent(<div className="open-data-information-drawer-item residences">
                                <h1>{divTitle}</h1>
                                <div className="open-data-item-information-container">
                                    {collapse}
                                </div>
                </div>); 
}
```

This function loads some jsx into the div below. (I use the Ant Design components collapse and list)

```
                   <List
                    className={ 'list-body' }
                    dataSource={ Object.keys(predefinedMenuItems) }
                    renderItem={ predefinedMenuItemId => (
                        <List.Item >
                            <div key={predefinedMenuItemId} onClick={ () => handleClick(predefinedMenuItemId)} className={'list-item'}>
                                <i className={ menuItemIconStyle(predefinedMenuItemId) }></i>
                                <span>{ predefinedMenuItems[predefinedMenuItemId].tooltip + ' info' }</span>
                            </div>
                        </List.Item>
                    )}
                />
                <div className="data-item-information">
                    {drawerContent}
                </div>
```

Now my problem is when I click a menu item (for example item 1, see screenshot 1) the collapse displays nicely. However if I click another item in the collapse is does nothing, but when I click on the same item in the menu again it reloads the collapse and the clicked item in the collapse displays (see screenshot 2).

How do I make it so that the Collapse works whenever I click it and not after I click the menu item again?

[screenshot of the layout of first clicking item 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRxtN.png) / [screenshot of the layout after clicking an item in the dropdown (collapse) and then clicking item 1 again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPW3B.png)

Comment: When using React you should avoid storing component instances in state, that includes the `useState` hook. `useState(<div></div>);` is going to lead to unpredictable behavior. I'll post an example of a way to accomplish the same thing as your code but without storing instances in state.

Comment: `const selectedMenuItem = menuItems.find(m => m.id === index);` <- this is not used. `const {data} = res;` <- what is `res`?

Comment: @RossAllen selectedMenuItem i need to delete yes, thanks. res is the data it loads, for example when you map through 'info'. Sorry I didn't post my entire code because it would be really long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid storing rendered components in state; React will act unpredictably because that's not a supported usage. Instead, store the smallest amount of data in state and render based off what's in state:

```js
const [activeCollapseKey, setActiveCollapseKey] = React.useState(0);
const [showDrawerContent, setShowDrawerContent] = useState(false);

let info = [];

function handleClick(index) {
  setShowDrawerContent(true);
}

function renderDrawerContent() {
  if (!showDrawerContent) return <div></div>;

  const divTitle = "Residence info";
  let res = openData.info;
  const { data } = res;

  info = [];
  _.isArray(data) ? (residencesInfo = data) : residencesInfo.push(data);

  return (
    <div className="open-data-information-drawer-item residences">
      <h1>{divTitle}</h1>
      <div className="open-data-item-information-container">
        <Collapse
          accordion
          activeKey={[activeCollapseKey]}
          onChange={key => {
            // @ts-ignore
            setActiveCollapseKey(key);
          }}
        >
          {info.map((data, idx) => {
            return (
              <Panel header="test" key={idx + 1}>
                testInfo
              </Panel>
            );
          })}
        </Collapse>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then to use it:

```js
<div className="data-item-information">{renderDrawerContent()}</div>
```